# semicolon and comma in for loops

Tags: c, loops

`for( i=0, i<3, i=i+1 )`

`for( i=0; i<4; i++ )`

I do not understand why they are same.

`for( i=0, i<3, i=i+1 )`
will start with i=0, then i=0+1=1, i=1+1=2, i=2+1=3, then 3 is not satisfied with i<3, then should close. So in the end, it repeats only 3 times isn't it? (i=0, 1, 2)

`for( i=0; i<4; i++ )`
will start with i=0, then i=1, i=2, i=3, when reach i=4, 4 is not satisfied with i<4, then should close. So in the end, it repeats 4 times (i=0, 1, 2, 3).

Am I wrong?

Comment: `C` ??`SAME` ?? how??

Comment: Also why is this user not clickable? :/

Comment: @MarounMaroun: The user has an account on the programmers site where he asked the question. The question was deemed a better fit here and moved over, but since he/she doesn't have an account here, the username is not clickable.

Answer (score 7):

This

```
for( i=0, i<3, i=i+1 )
```

is invalid construction and will not be compiled.

So these constructions are not the same,:)

And if you will even substitute commas for semicolons in the first construction

```
for( i=0; i<3; i=i+1 )
```

in any case they will not be the same because the first loop will have only 3 iterations while the second loop will have four iterations.

Comment: ah yes :)) you second point is right too. Too obvious to see :D